# Creating singly escaped single and double quotes where newlines are also present / python

Tags: python, string, bash, python-3.x

I need to transform a string containing single and double quotes and newline characters for use in a system call.  Consider the following input string:

```
"""one'two\nthree"four"""
```

This should be transformed to the following output string:

```
"$'one\'two\nthree\"four'"
```

So that it can be submitted as a message argument in a `git` commit command:

```
git commit --message=$'one\'two\nthree\"four'
```

The odd syntax with the leading `$` and surrounding single quotes `'` is a bash construct described in the bash manpage in the section on quoting (search for QUOTING).  I have tried many python functions including `str.replace`, `re.sub`, `json.dumps`, `repr`, and `str.encode('unicode-escape')`.  But none have yielded the required transformation.  It seems that, in this case, python is too high-level for its own good.  Suggestions on how to proceed will be very gratefully received.

The system call itself will be made using code like this (omitting the `try` block for clarity):

```
import subprocess
call = ["git", "commit", "--message", "'one\'two\nthree\"four'"]
cpi = subprocess.run(call)
```

I may also use a git library of some description, but I have not done my homework yet for that.

*Note*: the unnecessary `$` character in the last item in the above `call` list has been removed.

Comment: [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote)

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis-Hillard. Okay. I have done some trials using the `subprocess.run` call. Both my original input string and your reformatted string work (with the unnecessary `$` character removed)! It seems that the `subprocess` module is quite smart. I now have an answer to my question and this posting should be considered closed. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: That's nice to hear, I had deleted my answer because me and sub-processing haven't gotten to know each other well, yet. I'll un-delete since it seems it does partially apply. Great to see it worked out for you.

Comment: You don't need any further quoting with the list argument; the string containing the double and single quotes and newlines is passed directly to an `exec` function, bypassing the shell that would interpret the `$'...'` quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Your wanted command is erroneous at the moment, it is not a valid Python string since a right `"` is missing, it should be:

```
"$'one\'two\nthree\"four'"
```

This is easily constructed by a simple `.format` call:

```
>>> "$'{}'".format("""one'two\nthree"four""") == "$'one\'two\nthree\"four'"
True
```

Comment: Hello Jim, I just worked out that the trailing `"` was missing. Many thanks for your answer, I now need some time to consider it.

Comment: '$\'one\'two\nthree"four\'' ==  "$'one\'two\nthree\"four'"

Comment: @RobbieMorrison There is *no rush* to accept an answer. You can do so tomorrow. Questions without an accepted answer get more views and answers (hence a higher chance of a better answer).

Comment: Bakuriu is right, wait until you've found what you need, there's no rush. Those two strings are indeed equal, differing quotes don't mean they're different.

Comment: I am having trouble with this commenting system. Try again! The string comparison holds true for python but the actual output from the `format` command is `'$\'one\'two\nthree"four\''` which is not what I need. The system call will require an output string _exactly_ as I specified, with all _internal_ quote characters singly escaped. Again python is being a little too smart here.

Comment: You can try your result in bash by entering `$ echo <transformed string>`. This is the acid test. What python thinks about equality is not sufficiently strict. Thanks for the input so far.

Comment: @RobbieMorrison could you edit your question and show us the way you're providing the string to bash? If the question is "how do I create this specific string in Python" the current answer sufficiently addresses that.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard. The system call is now indicated, as you requested. As I noted earlier, bash requires the exact same output I indicated. Anything else will fail. This can easily be tested using `echo`, again as I indicated. Thanks very much for your interest.